# Save virtual attribute through another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `city` model and a `wood_production` model. A city has one `wood_production` and `wood_production` stores the amount of wood in that `city` (under column amount).

Now, I have a virtual attribute in the city model like:

```
has_one :wood_production
delegate :amount, :to => :wood_production, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true

def wood
    self.wood_production_amount
end
```

So, `wood` is actually taken from the `wood_production` model, from the column named `amount` (by delegation).

Now, I want to decrement wood via a city without using the intermediate `wood_production` model. Ideally, I want to be able to do:

```
city.decrement(:wood)
```

or at least

```
city.wood -= ..
```

If I try that now, the new wood value is not saved (after `self.save`). Any ideas on how I can save it correctly?

**EDIT**, here is a code I am trying now:

```
has_one :wood_production, :autosave => true
delegate :amount, :to => :wood_production, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true

    def wood
        self.wood_production_amount
    end

    def wood= amt
      wood_production_amount = amt
    end
```

Now, if I do:

```
u = User.first
c = u.cities.first
c.wood -= 1000
```

I get (which is indeed correct)

```
 => 7432.778424219838
```

But when I try to save:

```
1.9.2p290 :006 > c.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you can alias `wood_production_amount`:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wood_production, :autosave => true

  delegate :amount, :to => :wood_production, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true

  alias_method :wood,  :wood_production_amount
  alias_method :wood=, :wood_production_amount=

  # ...
end
```

This gives you `city.wood` and `city.wood = n`, and because Ruby is magic you automatically get `+=`, `-=`, etc. for free. Very handy.

If you want to be able to do `city.decrement(:wood)` (in addition to `city.wood += n`) you'll need to get a bit more magical.

```
def decrement name, amt=1
  # make sure it's an attribute we can set
  unless respond_to? "#{name}="
    raise ArgumentError, "Invalid attribute name for decrement"
  end

  # call the method by name to get the current value, then
  # subtract amt from it
  new_amt = send( name ) - amt

  # set the new amount
  send "#{name}=", new_amt 
end

# Usage:
some_city = City.find(...)

some_city.wood
# => 90

some_city.decrement :wood
# => 89

some_city.decrement :wood, 80
# =>  9
```

Incidentally it may be smarter to implement `increment` first, because it's the general case for `decrement`:

```
def increment name, amt=1
  check_argument name, :increment

  new_amt = send( name ) + amt

  send "#{name}=", new_amt 
end

def decrement name, amt=1
  check_argument name, :decrement

  increment name, -amt
end

private
def check_argument name, meth
  # make sure it's an attribute we can set
  unless respond_to? "#{name}="
    raise ArgumentError, "Invalid attribute name for #{meth}"
  end
end
```

Comment: While the "wood= amt" setter works for setting the value of the instance, when i do city.save, the value is not saved. (From Console -> c.wood -= 1000  => 7295.185450318195 1.9.2p290 :004 > c.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
 => true), nothing is executed as you see, no query.

Comment: Ah, sorry, saving the "parent" model does not automatically save its "children." For that you'll have to use the `:autosave => true` option on the relation. I've changed my code to reflect this. It also occurred to me (much too late IMO) that instead of defining `wood` and `wood=` methods you can just alias the delegated methods to those names. I've added this to my code as well.

Comment: even with autosave, i can't get it to save the value. I did not use the aliases, because i had inclusion errors in my modules for some reason. I will paste the code i currently have in my question so that you take a look if you want. I still can't save it though :/

Comment: Well, interesting, i found the problem. It seems saving through the delegation does not work, very interesting, could probably be something to fix in rails. So, trying c.wood -= 1000 and save does not work, but c.wood_production.amount -=1000 and then save works fine !

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :wood_production
```

or

```
 has_one :wood_production, :autosave => true
```